# CSVSimple ignoring line when enclosed field in double quotes has comma in it

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I'm trying to display a *very* large CSV file as a table which is generated from a program.
The output of the program is a compliant RFC 4180 CSV file, and as such any field which contains a comma is enclosed in double quotes `"`. However, CSVsimple ignores this line. How do I fix this?

Sample CSV file:

```
Rank,Name,Median_score,Cooperation_rating,Wins,Initial_C_rate,CC_rate,CD_rate,DC_rate,DD_rate,CC_to_C_rate,CD_to_C_rate,DC_to_C_rate,DD_to_C_rate
0,Evolved ANN 5 Noise 05,2.4905443548387094,0.4924381048387097,126.5,0.9506048387096774,0.3979901209677421,0.09444798387096777,0.19763709677419344,0.3099247983870967,0.8131456249267315,0.6305697857143637,0.43896754433182866,0.16263751323498196
1,"DBS: 0.75, 3, 4, 3, 5",2.431239919354839,0.3988991935483871,135.0,0.9509274193548387,0.3164965725806451,0.08240262096774195,0.22036794354838693,0.38073286290322605,0.8341798279957744,0.49733465333274995,0.27789064893581683,0.22881418670824838
2,Second by RichardHufford,2.3971673387096772,0.40838165322580644,132.0,0.9488709677419355,0.3064282258064516,0.10195342741935484,0.22199536290322577,0.36962298387096776,0.8199664917952298,0.15203283502430787,0.6611790544745667,0.07946789603790326
3,Revised Downing,2.3799798387096773,0.39448004032258066,119.0,0.9506048387096774,0.2698252016129031,0.1246548387096774,0.24078346774193546,0.364736491935484,0.7081181279100983,0.419492212806942,0.38152788294217344,0.25469205691448726
4,Evolved FSM 16 Noise 05,2.37633064516129,0.44351814516129034,111.0,0.9502419354838709,0.3406358870967743,0.1028822580645161,0.1989620967741934,0.3575197580645161,0.8603392240480966,0.48914238424923623,0.4119413240129918,0.09541845008601585
5,Evolved ANN,2.372368951612903,0.41917661290322583,136.0,0.9515322580645161,0.3513897177419357,0.0677868951612903,0.1842770161290322,0.3965463709677418,0.8133328916697765,0.6177725034894199,0.29406405406264435,0.07026965468508092
6,Second by Borufsen,2.316108870967742,0.5484534274193549,116.0,0.9478225806451613,0.42302157258064493,0.1254318548387097,0.1488096774193549,0.3027368951612904,0.9150910248577407,0.13194067320351477,0.6821776531424888,0.144335054814451
```

My current LaTeX code:

```latex
\csvreader[
respect all,
longtable = |r|l|,
head to column names
]{tournaments/gpb_tf2t_full/noisy_summary.csv}%
{}{%
\Rank & \Name
}%
```

Will have row 3 (the one with rank 1 and name `"DBS: 0.75, 3, 4, 3, 5"`) be ignored, as it seems CSVsimple is parsing the `,` to establish a new column (which is against the spec).

Comment: You may report bugs here: https://github.com/T-F-S/csvsimple/issues

Comment: Oh, that might be a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may hack `\__csvsim_read_line:` command in `csvsimple-l3`, using `l3regex` to replace every `"..."` with `{...}`, as long as there are no `""` or newlines in it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
Rank,Name,Median_score,Cooperation_rating,Wins,Initial_C_rate,CC_rate,CD_rate,DC_rate,DD_rate,CC_to_C_rate,CD_to_C_rate,DC_to_C_rate,DD_to_C_rate
0,Evolved ANN 5 Noise 05,2.4905443548387094,0.4924381048387097,126.5,0.9506048387096774,0.3979901209677421,0.09444798387096777,0.19763709677419344,0.3099247983870967,0.8131456249267315,0.6305697857143637,0.43896754433182866,0.16263751323498196
1,"DBS: 0.75, 3, 4, 3, 5",2.431239919354839,0.3988991935483871,135.0,0.9509274193548387,0.3164965725806451,0.08240262096774195,0.22036794354838693,0.38073286290322605,0.8341798279957744,0.49733465333274995,0.27789064893581683,0.22881418670824838
2,Second by RichardHufford,2.3971673387096772,0.40838165322580644,132.0,0.9488709677419355,0.3064282258064516,0.10195342741935484,0.22199536290322577,0.36962298387096776,0.8199664917952298,0.15203283502430787,0.6611790544745667,0.07946789603790326
3,Revised Downing,2.3799798387096773,0.39448004032258066,119.0,0.9506048387096774,0.2698252016129031,0.1246548387096774,0.24078346774193546,0.364736491935484,0.7081181279100983,0.419492212806942,0.38152788294217344,0.25469205691448726
4,Evolved FSM 16 Noise 05,2.37633064516129,0.44351814516129034,111.0,0.9502419354838709,0.3406358870967743,0.1028822580645161,0.1989620967741934,0.3575197580645161,0.8603392240480966,0.48914238424923623,0.4119413240129918,0.09541845008601585
5,Evolved ANN,2.372368951612903,0.41917661290322583,136.0,0.9515322580645161,0.3513897177419357,0.0677868951612903,0.1842770161290322,0.3965463709677418,0.8133328916697765,0.6177725034894199,0.29406405406264435,0.07026965468508092
6,Second by Borufsen,2.316108870967742,0.5484534274193549,116.0,0.9478225806451613,0.42302157258064493,0.1254318548387097,0.1488096774193549,0.3027368951612904,0.9150910248577407,0.13194067320351477,0.6821776531424888,0.144335054814451
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\appto\__csvsim_read_line:{
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_tl \csvline
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { "([^"]+)" } { {\1} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_gset_eq:NN \csvline \l_tmpa_tl
}{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  respect all,
  longtable = |r|l|,
  head to column names,
]{\jobname.csv}{}{
  \Rank & \Name
}

\end{document}
```

[image]